# How to access proto.EnumValueOptions extension values

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have similar setup as bellow, how can I access my extension values from `XYZ` enum using "github.com/golang/protobuf/proto"?

```
  extend google.protobuf.EnumValueOptions {
    Details meta = 50001;
  }

  message Details {
    string description = 1;
  }

  enum MyEnum {
    MY_ENUM_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
    XYZ = 1 [deprecated=true, (meta) = {description: "lorem ipsum"}];
  }
```

I'm aware of `proto.GetExtension(proto.Message, proto.ExtensionDesc)`, however I wasn't able to figure out how it can be used for the enum...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit late but I've just run into the same; you can do it like this:

```
fd, _ := descriptor.ForMessage(&pb.Details{})
for _, e := range fd.EnumType {
    if e.GetName() == "MyEnum" {
        for _, v := range e.Value {
            ext, err := proto.GetExtension(v.Options, pb.E_Meta)
            if err == nil {
                details := ext.(*pb.Details)
                // do stuff with details
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There might be a more direct way of getting the enum descriptor, although I haven't managed after a bit of wrangling.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the methods used in current best answer is now deprecated and it is a bit lengthy.

Here is how I got it:

```
// pd is the module of your complied protobuf files
fd := pd.File_name_of_your_proto_file_proto
enumDesc := fd.Enums().ByName("MyEnum")
if enumDesc == nil {
    panic()
}

enumValDesc := enumDesc.Values().ByName("XYZ")
if enumValDesc == nil {
    panic()
}

ext := proto.GetExtension(enumValDesc.Options(), pd.E_Meta)
if enumValDesc == nil {
    panic()
}

meta := ext.(*Details)
```

Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: I'll be honest. I have no clue how this works, but it worked.

Comment: If you want to avoid hardcoding the second string into your code, you can use this:

```
import (
 "google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect"
)

...

enumValDesc := enumDesc.Values().ByName(protoreflect.Name(pd.YourEnumType.String()))
...

Comment: Can you try to make it iterate? Then I could put it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

After many hours, I have found a method to access the description for the enum. Here is my implementation, I hope it helps.

In a file called enum.go in the same package as the generated .pb file, I added this method to the enum type that retrieves the description.

```
func (t MyEnum) GetValue() (*Details, error) {
    tt, err := proto.GetExtension(proto.MessageV1(t.Descriptor().Values().ByNumber(t.Number()).Options()), E_Details)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return tt.(*Details), nil
}
```

I am sure there is an easier way, but until somebody finds one, this should work.